# session for showing username that currently log in not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

So I'm trying to build success page for user that successfully logged in by showing greet to the username like this

```
Hi, <username>
```

I've done this by calling session from controller. After log in, the username doesn't show up, but when I try to reload the page, it showed up. This is not right. Here's code in **the view** that called the session:

```
<div><p style="text-align: center;">Hi, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('uname'); ?></p></div>
```

And here's the set session code in **controller**:

```
    //check user credentials
    $uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($username, $password);
    if(count($uresult)>0)
    {
        //set session
        $sess_data = array('login' => TRUE, 'uname' => $uresult[0]->username,'uid' => $uresult[0]->id);
        $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
        $this->load->library('../controllers/page');
        $this->page->success();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class = "alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email/Password</div>');
        $this->load->library('../controllers/page');
        $this->page->login();

    }
```

Anyone knows what should I do to fix this up?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**
The line in controller

```
redirect('page/success');
```

is calling success() method in my page.php controller. Code for success():

```
function success(){
$this->load->view('page_header');
$this->load->view('content_success');
$this->load->view('page_footer');

}
```

The `content_success` view is where I put the calling session for showing username.

Comment: could you please share the code present in `$this->page->success();`

Comment: @NishantNair done. Please let me know if there's another thing I missed

Comment: You should use `redirect` instead of load

Comment: @NishantNair in success() method?

Comment: yes `redirect('page/success');` use this instead of `$this->page->success();`

Comment: it works! I created another function to load header, content, and footer view and then call that method in another method that will be called in set session statement. Thank you for your help

Comment: Great..! Have a nice day...!